# Como remover agrupamento de dados em eixo no ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Tenho o conjunto de dados abaixo, onde faço a plotagem dos valores sobre um eixo de datas, como pode haver datas iguais na base, por default o ggplot faz o agrupamento desses dados, porém a visualização correta seria não agrupar. Uma solução que encontrei foi mesclar os dados de data e tempo, formando a coluna "DATE_TIME", de certa forma resolve o problema, no entanto a visualização não fica muito elegante, queria saber se existe alguma outra maneira de remover esse agrupamento dos dados?

**Meus dados:**

```
dataset = 
structure(list(GPHY_G_TH_PPM = c(21.3, 22.1, 22.1, 22.4, 22.7, 
22.8, 22.9, 23.3, 23.7, 23.8, 23.8), GPHY_G_DATE = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("2019-06-12T00:00:00.0000000", 
"2019-06-13T00:00:00.0000000", "2019-06-17T00:00:00.0000000"), class = "factor"), 
    TITULO = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L), .Label = "Gama - Standard Low Value (LL)", class = "factor"), 
    DATE_TIME = structure(c(7L, 5L, 9L, 3L, 2L, 8L, 4L, 10L, 
    1L, 6L, 11L), .Label = c("12/06/2019 09:17:36", "12/06/2019 10:37:40", 
    "12/06/2019 14:27:49", "12/06/2019 16:01:31", "13/06/2019 08:45:57", 
    "13/06/2019 10:34:01", "13/06/2019 13:39:34", "13/06/2019 16:07:35", 
    "13/06/2019 17:06:15", "17/06/2019 09:06:26", "17/06/2019 10:35:16"
    ), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```

**Script**

```
library("ggplot2")
library("tibble")
library("tidyr")

dataset$GPHY_G_DATE = factor(as.Date(dataset$GPHY_G_DATE))
colnames(dataset) = c("TH_PPM", "DATE", "TITULO", "DATE_TIME")

zone_data <- tibble(ymin = 20, ymax = 24, xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf)
zone_data$Type =  c("TH_PPM")
zone_data$cor_linha_ponto = c("#0461FE")

dataset <- dataset %>% pivot_longer(
      cols=colnames(dataset)[1],
      names_to = "Set", values_to = "Measurement"
)

p  =  ggplot(dataset, aes(x = DATE, y=Measurement)) +
      geom_line(aes(group=Set, color=Set), size=1) +
      geom_point(aes(color=Set, shape=Set), size=2, shape=15) +
      scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma) + 
      
      scale_color_manual(values=zone_data$cor_linha_ponto) +
      
      theme_bw() +
      theme(legend.position = "bottom",
            legend.title = element_blank(),
            panel.background = element_blank(), 
            panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
            panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
            axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 65, vjust = 1, hjust = 1),
            plot.title = element_text(size=12, face='bold', hjust = 0.5)) +
      labs(y = "TH (ppm)", x="", title = unique(dataset$TITULO)) +
      
      geom_rect(mapping = aes(ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax, xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax), 
                data = zone_data, alpha = 0.2, fill = zone_data$cor_linha_ponto,inherit.aes = FALSE) +
      geom_blank() 

p
```

**Output errado com o campo DATE**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Output correto com  campo DATE_TIME**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém gostaria de omitir o tempo no eixo x.

Comment: Isto é só uma amostra de dados? Nos dados reais há mais que um `Set`?

Comment: Sim, é só uma amostra, são três set.

Answer (score 4):

Esta solução não é exatamente igual à da pergunta uma vez que o painel azul do fundo preenche a área completamente.

Algumas diferenças no código são as seguintes:

1. Os títulos de colunas começados por `"GPHY_G_"` foram mudados com `sub`;
2. a tabela `zone_data` deixa de ser necessária;
3. `geom_point` e `geom_line` não precisam de `aes`, a cor dos pontos e da linha é estabelecida logo na chamada inicial a `ggplot`;
4. `panel.background` define o fundo azul claro;

Mas a diferença que a pergunta pedia é em relação aos pontos estarem agregados. Isso deve-se a se ter `DATE_TIME` com classe `"factor"`.

A solução é o pipe transformar essa coluna em classe `"POSIXct"`.

```
library("ggplot2")
library("tibble")
library("tidyr")
library("dplyr")

#colnames(dataset) <- c("TH_PPM", "DATE", "TITULO", "DATE_TIME")
colnames(dataset) <- sub("GPHY_G_", "", colnames(dataset))

dataset %>% 
  mutate(DATE = as.Date(DATE),
         DATE_TIME = as.POSIXct(DATE_TIME, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC")) %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = colnames(dataset)[1],
    names_to = "Set", 
    values_to = "Measurement"
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = DATE_TIME, y = Measurement, colour = Set)) +
  geom_line(size = 1) +
  geom_point(size = 2, shape = 15) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma) + 
  scale_x_datetime(date_labels = "%d %b %Y") +
  scale_color_manual(values = unique(zone_data$cor_linha_ponto)) +
  labs(y = "TH (ppm)", x="", title = unique(dataset$TITULO)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#cddfff"), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.major.x = element_line(color = "lightgrey", size = 0.25),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 65, vjust = 1, hjust = 1),
        plot.title = element_text(size=12, face='bold', hjust = 0.5))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá @Rui Barradas, obrigado pela solução, a faixa azul é necessária, pois define os limites do elemento "TH", sua solução resolve um ponto, porém o gráfico fica um pouco distorcido em relação ao original.